# disabling responsiveness in bootstrap for mobile phones and tablets

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've developed a web site using bootstrap and I did not include the bootstrap-respinsive.min.css in the code. Everything seems to work fine on desktops, but when accessed from mobile or tablet its getting shrunk and thus its getting messed up.

How can I make my code stick to the a minimum scale down width? below is my HTML head

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="Obytes, Orange Bytes, Startup, Django, Python, PostgreSQL" name="keywords">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="img/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font.css"/>


    <title>The title</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say you did not include the responsive css file, but your code shows otherwise. Can you please clarify?

Comment: sorry this was by mistake, i was experimenting with the responsive and copied it as it is. I just fixed it..

Comment: Also confused as to why you'd be using Bootstrap if you don't want a responsive site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue I see is no `<body>` tags in your code. This may be causing some issues for you.

Second, without knowing the contents of your `style.css` I can only guess. Having said that I'm thinking the `min-width` setting for your `body` tags may be getting overridden if you are indeed setting one.  The solution for this would be to either link to your CSS file *after* bootstrap.min.css like so:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Or you could set the min-width of your body tag after your existing code:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body{min-width: 1024px;}
</style>
```

Give these a try and let me know the result.

**Note: I am assuming you understand the cascading part of stylesheets. Please say so if you do not.**